# How to train with multiple CSV files in one H2O Driverless AI experiment

Tags: driverless-ai

I have multiple CSV files with the same headers.  All of them are quite large - several GBs.

Is there any way I can select multiple CSV files in a single experiment, without cascading them into a single file ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it.   I cannot select multiple datasets in an experiment, but I found I can import a folder containing multiple files into a single dataset using "Import Folder As File" button in the 'Add Dataset' menu.